# How to list all resources in the portal

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to find a resource in AWS, but I don't know what type of resource it was provisioned as.

I don't know AWS very well, but I'm having trouble finding the page in the portal that lists all of our resources in our account. How do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all resources for all regions using the tag editor https://resources.console.aws.amazon.com/r/tags

You should select all regions individually from the 'Regions*' dropdown and select only 'All resource types' from the Resource types* dropdown. Leave Tags empty and press 'Find Resources'

[image: Screenshot of AWS tag editor]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html), which  provides a detailed view of the configuration of AWS resources in your AWS account. This includes how the resources are related to one another and how they were configured in the past so that you can see how the configurations and relationships change over time.

An alternate approach, that I've used in the past, is to find resources that are not tagged. You can [search for untagged resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/scenario-finding-untagged.html) using the tag editor, and that should find all resources (including ones that might not show up in AWS Config). This approach allows you to search across all regions whereas AWS Config works on a region basis.

Answer (score 0):

As this is StackOverflow, I'm assuming it's a programming related question.

**To do this programatically, create an app to read resources of specific types**

[Python Example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/migrationec2.html)

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.instances
for instance in instances:
    print(instance.id, instance.instance_type)
```

[NodeJS Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ec2-example-managing-instances.html)

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});
var params = { DryRun: false };
ec2.describeInstances(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log("Success", JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```